# GAE Python Blobstore doesn't save filename containing unicode literals in Firefox only

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, firefox, unicode

I am developing an app which prompts the user to upload a file which is then available for download.
Here is the download handler:

```
class ViewPrezentacje(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler, BaseHandler):
    def get(self,blob_key):
        blob_key = str(urllib.unquote(blob_key))
        blob_info=blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key)
        self.send_blob(blob_info, save_as=urllib.quote(blob_info.filename.encode('utf-8')))
```

The file is downloaded with the correct file name (i.e. unicode literals are properly displayed) while using Chrome or IE, but in Firefox it is saved as a string of the form "%83%86%E3..."
Is there any way to make it work properly in Firefox?

Comment: Does the same behaviour exist with the dev_appserver, too? I've also experienced an encoding issue with blobstore due to this bug; https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2749

Comment: I had the same problem with this bug. I circumvented it by submitting form data via ajax and the file via upload file form - each of them triggering different handlers (apparently blobstore handler is not encoding unicode literals properly regardless of the means of sending them i.e. ajax or web form). However, the file name issue also occurs on the dev appserver.

Answer (score 1):

Sending filenames with non-ASCII characters in attachments is fraught with difficulty, as the original specification was broken and browser behaviours have varied.

You shouldn't be %-encoding (`urllib.quote`) the filename; Firefox is right to offer it as literal % sequences as a result. IE's behaviour of %-decoding sequences in the filename is incorrect, even though Chrome eventually went on to copy it.

Ultimately the right way to send non-ASCII filenames is to use the mechanism specified in [RFC6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266), which ends up with a header that looks like this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=UTF-8''foo-%c3%a4-%e2%82%ac.html
```

However:

- older browsers such as IE8 don't support it so if you care you should pass *something* as an ASCII-only `filename=` as well;
- BlobstoreDownloadHandler doesn't know about this mechanism.

The bit of BlobstoreDownloadHandler that needs fixing is this inner function in `send_blob`:

```
def send_attachment(filename):
  if isinstance(filename, unicode):
    filename = filename.encode('utf-8')
  self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = (
      _CONTENT_DISPOSITION_FORMAT % filename)
```

which really wants to do:

```
rfc6266_filename = "UTF-8''" + urllib.quote(filename.encode('utf-8'))
fallback_filename = filename.encode('us-ascii', 'ignore')
self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"; filename*=%s' % (rfc6266_filename, fallback_filename)
```

but unfortunately being an inner function makes it annoying to try to fix in a subclass. You could:

- override the whole of `send_blob` to replace the `send_attachment` inner function
- or maybe you can write `self.response.headers['Content-Disposition']` like this after calling `send_blob`? I'm not sure how GAE handles this
- or, probably most practical of all, give up on having Unicode filenames for now until GAE fixes it